# ActionMailer sending emails with empty body

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

It appears that around the time that I upgraded rails to 3.2.8, the body isn't being set when I create and send emails. No code around the mailers has changed in this time, with the exception of ActionMailer also upgrading to 3.2.8.

I have `beta_request_mailer.rb` in `app/mailers` with the following method:

```
def beta_request(request)
  mail(
    :to => "#{request[:name]} <#{request[:email]}>",
    :subject => 'Thanks for requesting an invite to xxxxx!'
  )
end
```

I also have a body file which worked fine: `app/views/beta_request_mailer/beta_request_email.html.erb`

The email is being sent fine, just without any body. Running in the console, the mail object that's created in beta_request has no body when running `mail.body`. If I set a body manually, that gets sent out.

What's changed that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing _email from file name

Comment: +1 It's obvious to me now, but I had to make sure my #action has the same name as my view

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting emails that arrived ok and with the correct subject, but with no content in the mail and found that using the .deliver! instead of just .deliver method cured the problem (though don't know why)

Comment: It should be noted that `deliver!` (as opposed to `deliver`) skips callbacks like email [interceptors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails), and thus should be used with caution.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was very interesting.

1. Firstly my Rails 4 application throw an error without layout file for mailer.
2. The I've created blank layout file `mailer.html.slim`. This resulted in mails delivered but without content.
3. Solution was to add `==yield` inside `mailer.html.slim`

Works like charm. Hope this was your issue and this helped you.